# How to capture **two fingers** touch while Explore By Touch is enabled?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am working on an app than needs to be able to capture gestures while accessibility and Explore By Touch is enable.
I have seen this answer for single touch - [How can I maintain a one pointer gesture when explore-by-touch is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328313/how-can-i-maintain-a-one-pointer-gesture-when-explore-by-touch-is-enabled/14988636#14988636)

But in my app the user must perform multi touch events. The problem is that due to the Explore By Touch function that makes two fingers touch to behave like a single touch on regular mode, all my two fingers gestures aren't recognized. Is there a way to override Explore By Touch completely or the entire Accessibility for my specific app? (I can perform the other accessibility functions from my app)

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973527/movement-of-simultaneous-two-bitmap-on-a-view-with-motionevent/14978588#14978588

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override Explore By Touch from within your code as it is an accessibility service that must be enabled/disabled by the user manually from within system settings.

However, TV Raman explains in his Google IO presentation - Making Android Apps Accessible 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3HliaMjL38

That the user can add a finger to the required gesture. so, a double-tapp passes a single tap to the underlying view, a 2-finger swipe passes a 1-finger swipe to the underlying view etc.

If you try pinch and zoom with 3 rather than 2-fingers in Chrome, that works. try your app with 3-finger gestures and see if your 2-finger gestures are now recognized.