# How to make touch event on bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, touch, touch-event

How to make touch event on bitmap I am getting touch event on my view this is my code. please check that what I do for making touch event on Bitmap  **resizedBitmap** . In this bitmap object I am receiving image from drawable folder and set murge on image view  Please help me.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.FloatMath;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class SingleImageView extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{


        public static Bitmap  Murge_Bitmap , Bitmap_recieve , bitmap1;
        ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
        ImageView imageview;    
        Button A4_Button ;
        Bitmap bitmap ,resizedBitmap;

        private static final String TAG = "Touch";
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f, MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

        // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
        PointF start = new PointF();
        PointF mid = new PointF();
        float oldDist = 1f;








        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.single_image_view);


            A4_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Make_A4_sheet);
            imageview =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageviewforsingleimage1); 
            Bitmap_recieve = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent()
                    .getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
            murge();  
            imageview.setImageBitmap(Murge_Bitmap);
                imageview.setOnTouchListener(this);

            A4_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SingleImageView.this, A4Copy.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }



        protected Bitmap murge() 
        { 
            Murge_Bitmap = null;
            Murge_Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(Murge_Bitmap);
            Resources res = getResources();
            bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sample_pic); 
            resizedBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 600, 600, true);
            Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
            Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable( resizedBitmap);
            //c.drawBitmap(Murge_Bitmap, 500,500, null);

            drawable1.setBounds(200, 200, 400, 400);
            drawable2.setBounds(200, 240, 400, 400);
            drawable1.draw(c);
            drawable2.draw(c);
            return Murge_Bitmap;
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            float scale;

            dumpEvent(event);
            // Handle touch events here...

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first finger down only
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: 

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                            - start.y); /*
                             * create the transformation in the matrix
                             * of points
                             */
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    // pinch zooming
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 5f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        /*
                         * setting the scaling of the matrix...if scale > 1 means
                         * zoom in...if scale < 1 means zoom out
                         */
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

            return true;
        }

        private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }


        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }

        private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                    "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int action = event.getAction();
            int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

            if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                    || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                sb.append("(pid ").append(
                        action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                sb.append(")");
            }

            sb.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                sb.append("#").append(i);
                sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
                sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
                sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
                if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                    sb.append(";");
            }

            sb.append("]");
            Log.d("Touch Event", sb.toString());
        } 
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973527/movement-of-simultaneous-two-bitmap-on-a-view-with-motionevent/14978588#14978588 this might help

Comment: how to implement in my code from this example please help